# Covariance models with lme and gls

Tags: r, model, statistics, covariance

I'm trying to fit several covariance models using gls and lme. My aim is to identify which covariance model fits my data better. I'm afraid, however, that I'm not specifying the code properly. Could someone take a look on my code and help me figuring out whether I'm pursuing everything correctly?

```
# Unstructured covariance matrix
UN <- gls(y ~ ses + time, data, corr=corSymm(form=~1|id), weights=varIdent(form=~1|time), method="REML", control=lmeControl(msMaxIter = 500, msVerbose = TRUE), na.action=na.omit)

# Independence covariance matrix
IN <- gls(y ~ ses + time, data, corr=NULL, weights=NULL, method="REML", control=lmeControl(msMaxIter = 500, msVerbose = TRUE))

# Fit Random Intercept Model (RI)
RI <- lme(y ~ ses + time, data, na.action=na.omit, method="REML", random=~1|id, control=lmeControl(msMaxIter = 200, msVerbose = TRUE))

# Fit Random Intercept and Slopes Model (RIAS)
RIAS <- lme(y ~ ses + time, data, na.action=na.omit, method="REML", random=~time | id, control=lmeControl(msMaxIter = 200, msVerbose = TRUE))

# Fit Compound Symmetry Error Covariance Matrix
CS <- gls(y ~ ses + time, data, na.action=na.omit, method="REML", correlation=corCompSymm(,form=~1|id), control=lmeControl(msMaxIter = 500, msVerbose = TRUE))

# Fit Heterogeneous Compound Symmetry Error Covariance Matrix
CSH <- gls(y ~ ses + time, data, na.action=na.omit, method="REML", correlation=corCompSymm(,form=~1|id), weights=varIdent(form=~1|time), control=lmeControl(msMaxIter = 500, msVerbose = TRUE))

# AR(1)
AR1 <- gls(y ~ ses + time, data, na.action=na.omit, method="REML", correlation=corAR1(,form=~1|id), control=lmeControl(msMaxIter = 200, msVerbose = TRUE))

# AR(1) under heterocedasticity
ARH1 <- gls(y ~ ses + time, data, na.action=na.omit, method="REML", correlation=corAR1(,form=~1|id), weights=varIdent(form=~1|time), control=lmeControl(msMaxIter = 200, msVerbose = TRUE))

# RI plus AR(1) 
RIAR1 <- lme(y ~ ses + time, data, na.action=na.omit, method="REML", random=~1|id, correlation=corAR1(form=~1|id), control=lmeControl(msMaxIter = 200, msVerbose = TRUE))

# RI plus AR(1) under heterocedasticity
RIARH1 <- lme(y ~ ses + time, data, na.action=na.omit, method="REML", random=~1|id, correlation=corAR1(form=~1|id), weights=varIdent(form=~1|time), control=lmeControl(msMaxIter = 200, msVerbose = TRUE))

# RIAS plus AR(1)  
RIASAR1<- lme(y ~ ses + time, data, na.action=na.omit, method="REML", random=~time|id, correlation=corAR1(form=~1|id), control=lmeControl(msMaxIter = 200, msVerbose = TRUE)) 

# ARMA(1,1)
ARMA11 <- gls(y ~ ses + time, data, na.action=na.omit, method="REML", correlation=corARMA(,form=~time|id, p=1, q=1), control=lmeControl(msMaxIter = 200, msVerbose = TRUE))

# ARMA(1,1) under heterocedasticity
ARMA11HE <- gls(y ~ ses + time, data, na.action=na.omit, method="REML", correlation=corARMA(,form=~time|id, p=1, q=1), weights=varIdent(form=~1|time),  control = lmeControl(msMaxIter = 200, msVerbose = TRUE))

# Fit Toeplitz Error Covariance Matrix
TOEP <- gls(y ~ ses + time, data, na.action=na.omit, method="REML", correlation=corARMA(,form=~1|id, p=3, q=0))

# RIAQS plus AR(1) allow for heterocedasticity
RIAQSAR1 <- lme(y ~ ses + time, data, na.action=na.omit, method="REML", weights=varPower(form=~time), random=~time + I(time^2)|id, correlation=corAR1(form=~time), control=lmeControl(msMaxIter = 200, msVerbose = TRUE))
```

thanks

Comment: This is a little bit of a "please debug my code for me" request ... have you looked at the results to see if they make sense?  You can make your code more compact by using `update()` to change just the relevant parts, e.g. `UN <- update(IN,corr=corSymm(form=~1|id), weights=varIdent(form=~1|time))`